# Create Distinct Instances of DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I'm creating a logger using EF6 and trying to create 2 instances of my `DbContext` because I'm logging 2 different things into (when this works) 2 different tables.

I'm using the same class to create both Contexts, but overriding `OnModelCreating` to (attempt to) store the info into separate tables:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  string tablePrefix = LogName + "_";
  modelBuilder.Types().Configure(entity => entity.ToTable(tablePrefix + entity.ClrType.Name));
  base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

However, it appears that OnModelCreating doesn't fire when I create another instance of my Context.  This makes sense from an optimization point of view, but I'd like to force the creation of a completely independent Context.

How do I force the creation of distinct Contexts that utilize the same class?

Comment: You should have two contexts. What you're doing is going to lead you into a world of pain. Stop now. Make two contexts, one for each logger. If you're doing this because you want `n` loggers in the future, then you should have a column on each table indicating the logger type, not a table per logger.

Comment: @Rob the intent is `n` loggers (where `n` is reasonably small).  You're probably right..I should just include the logger type in the table.